# what is Umbraco back office and what is umbraco back office extension, and what they do?

Tags: content-management-system, extension-methods, umbraco

what is Umbraco back office and what is umbraco back office extension, and what they do?

http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions?filter=free

I am trying to understand Umbraco and am going to important and trendy terms used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The umbraco back office is the area that you log into at http://example.com/umbraco/. This is the place where you administer your site, create content nodes, manage users, etc. You can also manage your templates and style sheets from here.

Back office extensions are packages in which other users have extended some functionality of the back office. This includes custom data types (the things you add to document types to collect data from users when they create nodes) like the [Google Maps DataType](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/google-maps-datatype), or tools and utilities that make life easier in the back office like [F.A.L.M. Housekeeping](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/falm-housekeeping).

**In regards to your comment:**

There are a probably a number of ways to solve the problem.

Will a product ever have more than one category? If not, you can create a category document type and just create new product nodes under each category node. Your macro will simply list all caregory nodes.

Otherwise, you could put a data type on the product document type that allows you select the categories for it. A multi select list box or a checkbox list would probably be adequate. If the client wants to control what categories are available in this case you could use the [XPath CheckBoxList](http://ucomponents.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=XPathCheckBoxList&referringTitle=Documentation). The macro for this scenario would simply list the categories available and when you click on a category node you'd have another macro that filters the products based on their categories.

Comment: Thank you. I am a web designer. I also have a .net developer, who is struggling to understand Umbraco. I got a client, who want their product categories on left side of the webpage.(http://www.mkmedicalservices.com/anti-allergy.html) Till, now we have inserted the template, however, we are finding it difficult to create something like where we can make an interface where we (admin) or client himself can create categories and manage them and upload product information on the page. That would be helpful OR is there any back office extension as such that will help. Any input?

Comment: I tried to reply to your comment, but my reply was to long. I made it part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for going extra mile to help me. :)